# Angular2 Observable and Promise

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I started using Angular2 `Observable`, but I can't find something similar to `.then` that I used with `Promises`.

This is what I want to accomplish.

### code from header.component.ts

```
public login() {
    this._user = AuthService.getInstance().login(this._loginInfo);
}
```

### code from auth.service.ts

```
return this._httpClient.post('LoginAction', credentials)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(user => {
    return new User(user);
  });
```

With promises,  `login` function would return Promise, that would eventually transform to actual response from server. But with Observable this won't work.

Is there a way to do similar thing? I want to avoid need of putting subscribe inside `component`'s `login` function. I want to be able to do all the work in service, and to return actual object to `component`.

Also, I tried to create `Promise`, with `toPromise`, but I keep getting `toPromise is not a function`.

p.s. _httpClient is my wrapper around angular2 http in which I prepare request by adding some headers etc.

### edit

```
return this._httpClient.post('LoginAction', credentials)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .toPromise().    <-- i keep getting that it is not a function
  then(user => {
    return new User(user);
});
```

by doing this, my component will get object (which is what it need), and in service i could do additional things (like saving user to localstorage, once I logged him).

And I switched to `Promise`, because doing same with `Observable` is not working (or I am doing it wrong)?

I see that returned object is Observable (before calling toPromise), but I don't see `toPromise` function indeed.

Comment: "I want to be able to do all the work in service, and to return actual object to component." - You can't do this, because `httpClient.post` is async, so you need to provide callback for `then` function if you use Promise, or for `subscribe` function if you use RxJS Observable. There is async/await in ES6 (https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) that can make your code look like linear, but it works by using callbacks underneath.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you call `subscribe(...)` a `Subscription` is returned which doesn't have a `toPromise()`. If you move the code from `subscribe` to `map` you can use `toPromise()` instead of `subscribe`

```ts
return this._httpClient.post('LoginAction', credentials)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(user => {
    return new User(user);
  }).toPromise();
```

and the caller will get a `Promise` where he can get the value using

```ts
public login() {
    this._user = AuthService.getInstance().login(this._loginInfo)
    .then(result => {
      doSomething();
    });
}
```

but you get the same result if you omit `.toPromise() and the caller uses it like

```ts
public login() {
    this._user = AuthService.getInstance().login(this._loginInfo)
    .subscribe(result => {
      doSomething();
    });
}
```

where the only difference is `subscribe()` instead of `then()` and if the user of the library prefers the reactive style he will prefer using `subscribe()` like he is used to.

Comment: `subscribe` returns a `Disposable` and not a _Subscription_

Comment: `subscribe(observerOrNext?: PartialObserver<T> | ((value: T) => void), error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;`

Comment: I don't know where you take it from, look here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/81626546d6fc52e343c75e4c9f698d207b11b58d/src/Observable.ts#L86. Maybe `Disposable` is rxjs4. Angular uses rxjs5.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for help. Please check my edited question, I tried to clarify it a bit more.

Comment: Then you need to add `import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";`

Answer (score 22):

You need to import the Rx toPromise operator like

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

From Angular2 documentation

We are advise to add this in `rxjs-extension.ts`

````
```
// Observable class extensions 
   import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; 
   import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Observable operators 
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'; 
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime'; 
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged'; 
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'; 
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'; 
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'; 
```
````

And import it at `app.module.ts` (Root Module)

`import './rxjs-extensions';`

This will help us to prevent further error.